# Navbar DropDown Item Cannot Hide by Default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I create **Bootstrap** Navbar with `dropdown-item` inside, however the menu itself cannot hide by default.

Please see images, before clicked (default) :
[image]

after clicked :

[image]

My Code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
<div class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="img/logo.png" />
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="navbar-nav flexbox_basic-spaceAround border-yellow">


        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
               href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
               role="button"
               data-toggle="dropdown"
               aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false">
                Stores
            </a>
            <div id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item">Custom Order</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Industry</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Business</div>

        <div class="nav-item">
            <button class="bg-primary">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (i'm using FlexBox CSS3) :

```
.flexbox_basic-spaceAround {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.flexbox_basic-spaceAround div {
    display: flex;
}
```

i'm using Boostrap 4-beta-2 btw...

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

first you should give **display:none** for div with class name dropdown menu,
after clicking/on hover of menu button give **display:block** for dropdown-menu div